Select collectionsMat table rows based on mouse and Shift as Excel
I work with angular material table,my table contains a selection Model to handle the selected All and selected One and contains some columns and some rows.
what i have now that i can select all or select one element and all is good,
what i need is to handle the event Shift click as Excel to select the checkbox as a multiples rows.
and when i select a collection in same time there checkbox will be selected and i have the possibility to uncheck one one i click on it.(i found this behaviour in ag grid table but i need that with mat table )
this gif explains the behaviours , just i need to select the element between start end , i can select to range and i push them in fianlArray..
Behaviour
my Html code is like that :
<ng-container matColumnDef="select">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    <mat-checkbox 
      id="allCheck" 
      (change)="setAllChekedOrUnchecked($event)"
      [checked]="isAllElementSelected" 
      [indeterminate]="iSsomeElementsSelected">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <mat-checkbox 
      [checked]="row.complete" 
      (click)="oneElementSelected($event, row)">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </td>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="entityCode">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>TOUTES</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="cursor: pointer">
    <span (click)="openConfirmationDialog(element)">{{ element.entityCode }}</span>
  </td> 
</ng-container>`


my ts file :
dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<any>;
selection = new SelectionModel<Interclassement>(true, []);
selectedElements: Interclassement[] = [];

setAllChekedOrUnchecked($event: MatLegacyCheckboxChange) {
  this.dataSource.data.forEach(elt => {
    elt.complete = $event.checked;
  });
  this.isAllElementSelected = $event.checked;
  
  if ($event.checked) {
    this.selection.select(...this.dataSource.data);
  } else {
    this.selection.clear();
  }
  
  this.iSsomeElementsSelected = this.someElementsSelected();
}

iSsomeElementsSelected: boolean = false;

someElementsSelected() {
  return this.selection.selected.some(t => t.complete && !this.isAllElementSelected);
}

oneElementSelected($event: any, row: any) {
  if ($event.checked) {
    this.selection.select(row);
  } else {
    this.selection.deselect(row);
  }
  
  row.complete = $event.checked;
  this.isAllElementSelected = this.selection.selected.length === this.dataSource.data.length;
  this.iSsomeElementsSelected = this.someElementsSelected();
}

// Shift+Click logic : but it doesn't work.
lastSelectedId: number | null = null;

getRowRange(idA: number, idB: number): any[] {
  const rows = this.dataSource.data;
  const startIndex = rows.findIndex(row => row.id === idA);
  const endIndex = rows.findIndex(row => row.id === idB);

  if (startIndex === -1 || endIndex === -1) {
    throw new Error('Invalid row range');
  }

  const [from, to] = startIndex < endIndex ? [startIndex, endIndex] : [endIndex, startIndex];
  return rows.slice(from, to + 1);
}

toggleSelection(event: MouseEvent, row: any) {
  if (event.shiftKey && this.lastSelectedId !== null) {
    const rowsToToggle = this.getRowRange(this.lastSelectedId, row.id);
    const shouldSelect = !this.selection.isSelected(rowsToToggle[0]);

    rowsToToggle.forEach(row => {
      if (shouldSelect) {
        this.selection.select(row);
      } else {
        this.selection.deselect(row);
      }
    });
  } else {
    this.selection.toggle(row);
  }

  this.lastSelectedId = row.id;
}



Yes, it is possible to implement Shift + Click functionality in an Angular Material table (mat-table) for multi-selecting rows. Although Angular Material's selection model does not natively support shift-based selection (like Excel or ag-Grid), you can manually handle this by tracking the selected range of rows and updating the selection accordingly.
ts file
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-selection',
  templateUrl: './table-selection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-selection.component.css']
})
export class TableSelectionComponent {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['select', 'name'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  selection = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, []);
  
  lastSelectedIndex: number = -1;

  /** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected()
      ? this.selection.clear()
      : this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }

  /** The label for the checkbox on the passed row */
  checkboxLabel(row?: Element): string {
    if (!row) {
      return `${this.isAllSelected() ? 'deselect' : 'select'} all`;
    }
    return `${this.selection.isSelected(row) ? 'deselect' : 'select'} row ${row.name}`;
  }

  /** Handles selection based on shift-click functionality */
  handleRowSelection(event: MouseEvent, row: Element, index: number) {
    if (event.shiftKey && this.lastSelectedIndex !== -1) {
      const start = Math.min(this.lastSelectedIndex, index);
      const end = Math.max(this.lastSelectedIndex, index);
      for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        this.selection.select(this.dataSource.data[i]);
      }
    } else {
      this.selection.toggle(row);
    }
    this.lastSelectedIndex = index;
  }
}

export interface Element {
  name: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  { name: 'Hydrogen' },
  { name: 'Helium' },
  { name: 'Lithium' },
  { name: 'Beryllium' },
  { name: 'Boron' },
];

HTML file
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Checkbox Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox
        (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
        [checked]="isAllSelected()"
        [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
      <mat-checkbox
        (click)="handleRowSelection($event, row, i)"
        [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>


where you use this functions checkboxLabel ? , the code it works for you ? do you have a stack blitz example
